# Excel update cell status if all cells is completed status

Tags: excel

I have a column A2-A10, and each cell in it has a data validated dropdown between multiple status "Not started, "status 1", "status 2", "Completed"

What should be the formula for me to update A1 if all cells point to completed it will show as "Completed", if no cells have started it will show "Not started", and if there are still cells in progress it will show "WIP"?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A10,"Completed") = 9, "Completed",IF(COUNTIF(A2:A10,"Not Started") = 9,"Not Started","WIP"))
```

This is dependent on there being exactly 9 entries though.

If you place this formula into another cell, and then reference it instead of the 9, you will have a solution. It will count all the cells that are not blank up until the blank. This solution allows up until row 600 to be used, edit as needed.

```
=MIN(IF(A2:A600="",ROW(A2:A600)-ROW(A2)+1))-1
```

You will need to press 'Shift + Enter' when entering this into a new cell. If done correctly excel will change the formula to

```
{=MIN(IF(A2:A600="",ROW(A2:A600)-ROW(A2)+1))-1}
```

the resulting formula, assuming the the count function is in B1 is

```
=IF(COUNTIF(A2:A10,"Completed") = B1, "Completed",IF(COUNTIF(A2:A10,"Not Started") = B1,"Not Started","WIP"))
```

Edit: Updated solution to meet new dynamic requirements.

Comment: This works fine, is there a better formula to not have a limited range of 9? I intend to expand the range to accomodate additional tasks if applicable.